# Show progress over long sql execute command in python

Tags: python, tqdm

I created a python script that opens a large SQL file (+50k rows) with inserts onto a table.

The code runs fine, but takes hours, and I was wondering if I could display a progress bar (tqdm doesnt seem to work on this scenario) or just show the "passing time"

Code:

```
def runScript(file):
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        sql = f.read()
    ...
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        c.execute(sql)  # --> this takes a lot of time
```

tqdm doesnt work (or at least doesnt show anything).

I could read row by row and use tqdm, but it takes WAY MORE time.

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can print progress to log file. The current time after each batch of rows e.g. 1000 rows. So that you can get an idea of how much time has passed and how much time is remaining to complete the task.

```
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    for i in range(0, len(sql), 1000):
        c.execute(sql[i:i+1000])
        print(f"{time.ctime()} : {i} rows done")
```

Comment: I cant really split the file....  but I will try something along this idea